# jquery simple ajax load without loading its wrapper DIV

Tags: jquery

I have a content (#content) at external file (test.html) to load into another DIV (#result) at index.html:

**test.html:**

```
<div id="content">This text should not be loaded with its DIV. <strong> May contain other tags</strong></div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#result').load('test.html #content');
```

**index.html result, unexpected:**

```
<div id="result"><div id="content">This text should not be loaded with its DIV. <strong> May contain other tags</strong></div></div>
```

**index.html result, expected:**

```
<div id="result">This text should not be loaded with its DIV. <strong> May contain other tags</strong></div>
```

How do you load only the actual content/ HTML of the #content which may also contain other tags, but only without its wrapper DIV (#content)?
The reason is to simply avoid unneeded divities which also may conflict with other styled DIVs by mistake.

Any hint is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: your markup seems to be broken( missing closing ")

Comment: You cannot do that with `.load()`

Comment: Thanks. Please provide as answer so I can mark even if its a no :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a thought.  What if you use a temporary tag as a workspace?

This jQuery javascript...

```
$('#workarea').load('test.html #content');
```

... might produce this result.  Notice that the workarea is hidden:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="workarea" style="display: none"><div id="content>This text should not be loaded with its DIV</div></div>
```

Then, you could move it to the result with this...

```
$('#result').html($('#workarea').html());
```

It should produce this result.

```
<div id="result">This text should not be loaded with its DIV</div>
<div id="workarea" style="display: none"><div id="content></div></div>
```

**Edit:**

Here's the complete script all in one place:

```
$('#workarea').load('test.html #content');
$('#result').html($('#workarea').html());
```

You would use these two lines instead of your one line.  If I understand correctly, it should produce the expected result in the query above.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Do you meant all inline in a file? The reason I used external file is because those HTML are too many to stay in a single page. Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @swan does that clarify?  You would just change your one jquery line to my two lines.  I split it up in my explanation to show what it was doing step by step.

Comment: Your idea brings me to a better solution. Yours is actually much better, and reduces lots of http requests. Load only a single HTML, and then broken down by ID from those loaded HTML, and finally insert each of the ID into parent HTML small divities. Brilliant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get the the result of .load() into a var.
You can do this.

```
var result = ... load line ...
var outResult = $(result);
// now strip the div out of outResult using jquery......
outResult = StripContentDiv(outResult);
$('#result').html(outResult);
```

Sorry I can't be more specific as I am not a jquery expert.

Comment: What function is StripContentDiv, is it builtin jquery, or custom? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it thats you look

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#result').load('test.html #content', function () {
    $('#content', this).text;
     });
   });
```

:P xD by JNE

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the following function is too late. #content is already loaded with its DIV.